Set of points where a continuous function is Holder is Borel.
A continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is Holder at $x$ if there exists $C,\epsilon > 0$ and $\alpha\in(0,1]$ satisfying
$$|f(x)- f(y)|\leq C|x-y|^\alpha,$$ whenever $|x-y| < \epsilon.$
Show that the set of points where $f$ is Holder is a Borel set.
Honestly I'm having trouble even getting this one off the ground. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Fairly easy to see that this is an open set.

Could you say a little more about that? What's throwing me off is that, the way the definition is stated, the values of $C, \epsilon$ and $\alpha$ all depend on the specific point $x$.
